# How to fix initialization errors?

Tags: c++

I am trying to realize the work of the design template.

In lines 62 and 63 there are errors. I do not understand what might not be so, because I did everything in the book.

Points that are running in `main()`:

- The client declaring and initializing an instances of the classes.
- The method gets called.
- 

```
C2440   Initialization: Unable to convert "Roma *" in "Human *"     62 
C2440   Initialization: Unable to convert "Natasha *" in "Human *"  63
```

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Human
{
public:
    virtual string Sex() = 0;
};

class Male : public Human
{
public:
    string Sex()
    {
        return "boy.\n";
    }
};

class Female : public Human 
{
public:
    string Sex()
    {
        return "I'm wooman!\n";
    }
};

class Gender 
{
public:
    virtual string DetermineTheSex() = 0;  
};

class Natasha : public Gender 
{
    Human* $sex; 
public:
    Natasha(Human* obj) : $sex(obj) {}
    string DetermineTheSex()
    {
        return "Natasha. " + $sex->Sex();
    }
};

class Roma : public Gender 
{
    Human* $sex;
public:
    Roma(Human* obj) : $sex(obj) {}
    string DetermineTheSex()
    {
        return "Roma " + $sex->Sex();
    }
};

int main() {
    
    Human* mal = new Male();
    Human* fem = new Female();

    Human* Person1 = new Roma(mal); // <<<---- error
    Human* Person2 = new Natasha(fem); // <<<---- error

    delete mal;
    delete fem;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The purpose looks unclear for me, but `Roma` and `Natasha` (and `Gender`, which is parent class of them) don't have `Human` as parent class.

Comment: there is no relation between `Human` and `Roma`, they are two unrelated classes. Why should that conversion work?

Comment: Well, class `Gender` is not a subclass of `Human`...

Comment: i didnt know that variables are allowed to start with `$`, looks ... weird

Comment: Having `Gender` as a base class to be inherited seems odd to me. Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. A "person" isn't a gender, but a person *might* have a gender. And what is the purpose of `Gender` when you already have the `Male` and `Female` classes? Your design just seems weird and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Gender
{
public:
    virtual string DetermineTheSex() = 0;
};

class Natasha : public Gender
```

`Roma` and `Natasha` inherit `Gender`, which is not a subclass of `Human`.

Therefore, you cannot use a `Human*` to point objects of this class. Change to `Gender*` and it will work:

```
Gender* Person1 = new Roma(mal);
Gender* Person2 = new Natasha(fem);
```

**Update:** Please don't use `$` to name variables in real projects, it may make someone's eyes bleed ;-)